# Rock, Paper, Scissors. Udacity, Classes and Subclasses

Tags: python, function, class, module, subclass

I'm getting this error:

```
move1 = self.p1.move()
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'move'
```

Basically I'm trying to understand how to call a module from one Class. The Player or RandomPlayer Class. From the Game Class.

Here is some of the code:

```
moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
class Player():
    def move(self):
        return 'rock'

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2    

class RandomPlayer(Player):  
    def move(self):
        p1 = random.choice(moves)
        p2 = random.choice(moves)
        return (p1, p2) 

class Game():

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
      self.p1 = p1
      self.p2 = p2

    def play_round(self, p1, p2):
        move1 = self.p1.move()
        move2 = self.p2.move()
        print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
        self.p1.learn(move1, move2)
        self.p2.learn(move2, move1)
        return (move1,move2)
```

Comment: `self.p1` is a string. How do you expect it to "move"?

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#) might be helpful.

Comment: `self.p1 = RandomPlayer()`

This worked for me. 

I took out the p1, p2 arguments.

`def __init__(self):`

` def play_round(self):`